# Finding an example of a Pythagorean triple, such that $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ but $\gcd(x,z)>1$, $\gcd(x,y)>1$, and $\gcd(y,z)>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Finding an example of a Pythagorean triple $x^2+y^2=z^2$, with the $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ but $\gcd(x,z)>1$, $\gcd(x,y)>1$, and $\gcd(y,z)>1$.

In order for this to be the case then I need to have an $x,y,z$ such that $x$ and $y$ have a common divisor that is greater than $1$, $y$ and $z$ to have a common divisor that is greater than $1$ but also not a common divisor of $x$ and $y$, and so on.

I attempted just to try some numbers with the formula
\begin{align} 
x &= 2st, \\
y &= t^2 - s^2 \\
z &= t^2 + s^2 
\end{align}
but to no avail. I've tried different methods to no avail, and I feel like the most promising method might be using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, but I don't know how to progress from there.

Comment: Presumably you intend to parametrize $(x, y, z)$ in terms of $(s, t)$ using [Euclid's formula](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) but you seem to have a typo.

Comment: Also, to clarify, what roles do $x$, $y$, and $z$ play in the Pythagorean equation? Can you edit to make this explicit? Is it meant to by $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$?

Comment: Note that if $\gcd(x,z)=d>1$, then $d|y$ as well. Why?

Comment: What you want is impossible. If $p$ is a prime that divides both $x$ and $y$, then it must divide $x^2+y^2=z^2$, hence $z$; if it divides both $x$ and $z$, then it must divide $y$, If it divides both $y$ and $z$, then it must divide $x$. You cannot have $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ and also have $\gcd(x,y)\gt 1$.

Answer (score 8):

Such an example doesn't exist.

If $x, y, z \in \mathbb Z$ are such that $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and if $p$ is a prime number that divides say both $x$ and $z$, then $p$ also divides $y^2 = z^2 - x^2$, hence $p$ divides $y$. So $\gcd(x, z) \neq 1 \implies \gcd(x, y, z) \neq 1$. The same implication holds for the premices $\gcd(x, y)$ and $\gcd(y, z)$ by the same kind of arguments.

Comment: Thats a relief, the question was in my textbook so I assumed there was an awser too it

Comment: Yes, Zag's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\,d\,$ be a common factor of $x$ and $y$

\begin{align*}
z^2=&x^2+y^2\\
=&(dq)^2+(dr)^2\\
=&d^2(q^2+r^2)\\
=&d^2s^2=z^2\\
\implies &d^2|z^2\\
\end{align*}
Then $\,d\,$ is a common factor of $z$ as well and there is no such triple as the one you seek.